# Mac Excel 2016, macro VBA, GetAsyncKeyState : File not found: user32

Tags: excel, vba, macos, user32

I want run Macro Excel in my **Mac** with **Excel 2016**.

My macro use [GetAsyncKeyState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/ms646293(v=vs.85).aspx) function. In first line of my macro file I have this import :

```
#If Win64 Then
    Declare PtrSafe Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal kState As Long) As Integer
#Else
    Private Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal vKey As Integer) As Integer
#End If
```

But when I run I have this error :

```
File not found: user32
```

Should I import something ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: That's a Windows API call you're making: pretty sure it's not there on the Mac.

Comment: Ok, thanks, but how can find equivalent of GetAsyncKeyState ? It's for detect key press.

Comment: Sorry - not a Mac user....